# Pandas StartsWith multiple options

Tags: regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
 <A>   "B"    C    _:D   <E>
  A     B    "C"    <D>   E>
 <A>   "B"   "C"     D   <E>
```

I am trying to find a way that will check which elements begin with '<' or '"' or '_:' and return a dataframe as follows:

```
  1     1     0     1     1
  0     0     1     1     0
  1     1     1     0     1
```

Without using apply, due to size of the dataframe.
Ideally my final dataframe becomes as follows:

```
 <A>   "B"    C    _:D   <E>    4
  A     B    "C"    <D>   E>    2
 <A>   "B"   "C"     D   <E>    4
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> how to add to the original dataframe a column containing the sum of 1s
>   found in the stack + unstack ?

```
In [59]: df['new'] = df.stack().str.contains(r'^(?:\"|<|_:)').astype(np.uint8).sum(level=0)

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
     0    1    2    3    4  new
0  <A>  "B"    C  _:D  <E>    4
1    A    B  "C"  <D>   E>    2
2   A<   B"   C"    D   E<    0  # pay attention at this row
```

**Old answer:**

try this:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains(r'^\"|<|_:').astype(np.uint8))
```

Demo:

```
In [33]: df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains(r'^\"|<|_:').astype(np.uint8))
Out[33]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  0  1  1
1  0  0  1  1  0
2  1  1  1  0  1
```

Or using `stack()` + `unstack()`:

```
In [36]: df.stack().str.contains(r'^\"|<|_:').astype(np.uint8).unstack()
Out[36]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  0  1  1
1  0  0  1  1  0
2  1  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thx @MaxU i updated my question to mention that i am trying to do it without apply.

Comment: @Kelaref, i've updated my answer... How many columns do you have in your real DF?

Comment: @Kelaref I don't think you'll get much quicker than MaxU's `stack() -> unstack()` approach.

Comment: @MaxU it works perfectly! The number of columns varies, but the number of rows are millions. Could you recommend how to add to the original dataframe a column containing the sum of 1s found in the stack + unstack ?

Comment: @Mitch do you have a faster alternative?

Comment: @Kelaref, can you post your desired data set?

Comment: Perhaps i would not need to unstack if i just need the count / sum ??

Comment: @MaxU just did. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kelaref, see UPDATE

Comment: @MaxU it needs to check if it starts with, not if it contains

Comment: @Kelaref, oops, sorry, it's fixed now - see updated result set